# How to create .swf in java by using 'ant' file & .mxml?

Tags: java, apache-flex

I am newer with flex technology.I am creating a chart using ant file & .mxml in eclipse my 'ant' file executes properly but it gives  following error when i opens a .swf file which is created auomatically:

Flex Error #1002: Flash Player 9.0.115 and above is required to support signed RSLs. Problem occurred when trying to load the RSL file:///C|/Users/cerebrum/workspace/Flex/textLayout_1.0.0.595.swz.  Upgrade your Flash Player and try again.

Please tell me how could i solve this error??

ant File:

```
<project name='Flex' default='mxml'>

 <target name='mxml'>
 <property name='compiler' location='C:\flex_sdk_4.0.0.14159A\bin\mxmlc.exe' />
 <exec executable='${compiler}' failonerror='true'>
 <arg line='-output C:\Users\cerebrum\workspace\Flex\CandleStick.swf' />
 <arg line='C:\Users\cerebrum\workspace\Flex\CandleStick.mxml' />
 </exec>
 <echo>mxml file compiled successfully</echo>
 <echo>swf file generated successfully</echo>
 </target>
</project>
```

CandleStick.mxml file:

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'ISO-8859-1'?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml">

 <mx:Label id = "eve"/>
 <mx:TextInput text = 'Click me to label eve' 
 click = 'eve.text = String("Rachel Weisz")'/>

 </mx:Application>
```

Comment: Well, have you tried upgrading Flash player?

Comment: yes,i upgraded flash player but nothing changed in output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 4.0 SDK by default targets the 10.0 player (in frameworks/flex-config.xml). This leads me to believe if you can compile just fine, but encounter this in the runtime, that your actual player isn't at this version or above. Also given your path to the swz, did you install the SDK in the same location as your workspace? - Typically it should be looking in something like: (path/to/sdk/**frameworks/rsls**) -and this is outside the workspace to keep eclipse from monkeying with it.

If you're trying to just get "up and running" for now, in your project properties > flex build path set: framework linkage to "merge", and uncheck "verify RSL digest". That should ensure all dependencies of the framework are baked into your final output (yes it'll be a bit bloated at this point).

As for player, you should be able go to adobe.com/go/get/flashplayer and it will tell you what version you have. Current production release is either 11.1 or 11.2 (R-Click the running swf).

Comment: please give any web link so that i will create .swf in eclipse helios

Comment: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flashbuilder/using/index.html

Is a good place to start, with the understanding of what your options are for Flex(Flash) Builder, but you can branch out and find the commandline triggers for ANT.

Also, look at the flex-config.xml in the SDK frameworks directory.